# The real time chart sometimes does not display when I switch the target

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, chart.js

My frontend uses React.
In my frontend, I have a map that displays many devices. When I click the device, it will show a real time chart that display some streaming data on the side. I am using this https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-streaming plugin for reat-time chart. It works fine with single device.

But sometimes when I click on another device, the chart does not show the line. And it will be fixed when I click it again. Also, I verified that the frontend can successfully receive the data and those data are correctly pushed into the corresponding data array of the RT chart.

Also,  when I click on another device, the chart sometimes still display the previous data array.
[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import "chartjs-plugin-streaming";
import { colors } from '@material-ui/core';
import client from '../../stompClient.js';

const initData = () => ({
    datasets: [
      {
        pointStyle: "circle",
        borderColor: colors.lightBlue[900],
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0,
        data: []
      }
    ]
  });
  
const options = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        type: "realtime",
        realtime: {
        }
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false,
      }
    }]
  },
  legend: {
    display: false,
    position: "right",
    labels: {
      boxWidth: 8,
      usePointStyle: true
    }
  }
};

const dataMap = new Map();

function findData(id,measurement) {
  var key = id+measurement
  
  if (dataMap.get(key) === undefined){
    let data = initData();
    dataMap.set(key, data);
    var callback = function(message) {
    
      if (message.body){
        var responseList = JSON.parse(message.body)
        for(var i = 0;i<responseList.length;i++){
          var response = responseList[i][1].match(/\d+/)[0]
          var dataset = JSON.stringify(data.datasets[0].data)
          var newData = {
            x: responseList[i][0],
            y: response
          }
          var newDataString = JSON.stringify(newData)
          if (!dataset.includes(newDataString)){
            data.datasets[0].data.push(newData);
            console.log(data.datasets[0].data.length)
          }
        }
      }
    };
    const destination = '/topic/'+key;
    console.log(destination);
    client.subscribe(destination,callback);
    return (dataMap.get(key));
  } else {    
    return (dataMap.get(key))
  }
}

function Refresh( id, client, measurement, focus, chart) {
  
    const input = {
      id: id,
      measurement: measurement,
      focus: focus
    }
    const inputString = JSON.stringify(input)
    client.publish({destination: '/app/request', body: inputString});
}

function RTChart(props) { 
  const data = findData(props.id,props.measurement)
  data.datasets[0].label = props.label;
  options.scales.xAxes[0].realtime.refresh = props.refreshIntervalmS;
  
    
  options.scales.xAxes[0].realtime.onRefresh = function(chart) { Refresh( props.id, client, props.measurement, props.focus, chart) }

  options.scales.xAxes[0].realtime.delay = props.delaymS;
  options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMin = props.offset;
  options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = props.offset + props.range;
  return(
    <Line data={data} options={options} />
  );
}
  
export default RTChart;
```

Comment: please read this and improve the question so people can actually help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @LeeLenalee which part do you confuse?

Comment: The part about how you do things, how its reproduceble so people can actually help you

Comment: @LeeLenalee how about now

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is related to library `react-chartjs-2`

https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2#working-with-multiple-datasets